# Magnesium Diboride - why was it missed?

Tags: history, superconductivity

In 2001 it was found to superconduct at 39K, which is about twice the record for materials up until the 1980s when the cuprate high temp superconductors were discovered/invented.

My question is really one of history - why did a compound so simple escape discovery? It really would have been a major discovery any time before the 1980s and might even have spurred on further searches that might have revealed the cuprates earlier.

Comment: I think the wikipedia entry provides the "usual" answer: "Properties depend greatly on composition and fabrication process. Many properties are anisotropic due to the layered structure. 'Dirty' samples, e.g., with oxides at the crystal boundaries, are different from 'clean' samples". Just like with cuprates, the properties depend on the way the material is synthesized. Who knows how many samples were tested without showing anything exciting?

Comment: Maybe, but it seems like one of those weird anomalies you occasionally get in science. The biggest (known) so far being fullerenes. They could have been discovered 100 years ago, but back then everyone "knew" that carbon only came in 3 forms.

Comment: Absolutely. Science is no more "linear" than history in that regard. One can do even better than fullerenes, for sure. Think about quasicrystals. If you want to go really big, think about the consequences of the economic decline of the Roman Empire, which basically wiped out scientific reasoning in the Western world for a whole millennium and then some. If we were to extrapolate what the Greeks new around the year 0 using modern science history, humanity should have landed on the Moon around the year 600 AD, or so! It just wasn't to be...

Comment: Well, except for the whim of one emperor the Chinese would have had men on the moon centuries ago. Check out Zheng He 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He#Size_of_the_ships

Comment: That's the nice thing about history... it's sometimes so random that we are free to speculate.